# How do i know if a class has a lot of responsability and How do i eliminate this problem

Tags: java, oop

Im doing a project about a restaurant, this restaurants has a lot of products (food) , i have a class Food Combo and this combo is conformed by **1 DRINK, 1 MAIN DISH and 2 EXTRAS.** This class has a lot methods and attributes, few of the methods do Mathematical operations and verifications when this should only return a price and bring his additional price

```
public class FoodCombo {

private ArrayList<Product> list = new ArrayList(); //Each Product has his own price
private boolean refill; //Do you want your drink to have refill?
private boolean supersizing; //
private final double COMBO_DISCOUNT = 0.20;
private final double REFILL_PRICE = 300;
private final double SUPERSIZING_PRICE = 300;

public FoodCombo() {
}

public void addProducto(Product product) {
    list.add(product);
}

/* This class needs one Main Dish, two Extras, and One Drink to be considered
as a Food Combo*/
public int countMainDishes() //1  


public int countExtras();     //2

public int countDrinks() //3  


public boolean isItCombo() {
}

;  //Use above methods to verify

//Calculate Methods
public double calculateSubPrice();

public double calculatediscount()

public double calculateRefill();

public double calculateSuperSize();

public double calculateTotal();

public String toString();
```

//I would aprreciate your suggestion :)

}

Im thinking into separate the responsability of this class into multiple classes so How many clases should i create to accomplish good practices of programming? and what should they do?

Comment: Have you researched the single responsibility principle? "How many classes should I create" sounds as if you want a personal walk through of the principle, regardless of how many examples of this principle exist online.

Comment: You should read about the SOLID principles, learn some coding patterns so you can finally try to apply some architecture to your future products.

Comment: @VinceEmigh i research a bit of this, but youre right , i should research more about this, thanks for your feedback :)

Comment: @ingkevin got it thank you bro

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing is: forget about the implementation.  So, "few of the methods do Mathematical operations and verifications when this should only return a price and bring his additional price" does not matter.

If you want to know whether a class is doing too much, write down what the class is for and what it does from a high-level perspective.  Then have a look at what you wrote and you will be able to tell whether it is doing too much.  Look for whether its responsibility is focused.

For example, if I have a class:

"This class is responsible for interfacing with the NRI G13 Coin Acceptor device, providing an API to accept coins, deal with errors, and report the amount of cash received."

Then even though its implementation may be doing a lot, the class itself is not doing too much.

Alternatively, if I have a class:

"This class reads from the database, processes the data, sends it to another server, and sends a copy to the browser."

Then even though its implementation may be fairly basic (all of these operations usually have one function to call from a library), the class is doing too much because it has responsibility for achieving too many outcomes.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback sir, the second paragraph is excellent, im going to apply some these things to my future projects and for this one.